# argMax uses only one thread and runs slow in clickhouse

Tags: window-functions, clickhouse

I have this query

```
SELECT argMax(IFNULL(A, 0), B) over (partition by C)
FROM db.table
WHERE B between 0 AND 10000000;
```

The problems are:

1. It uses only one thread (though I have 4 shards in a cluster, Distributed source table, many CPU's, max_threads=0)
2. It works really slow (query takes multiple minutes to finish

How to fix them?

Additional info is:

Column types:

```
A - int32
B - int32
C - int32
```

EXPLAIN PIPELINE

```
(Expression)
ExpressionTransform
  (Window)
  WindowTransform
    (Sorting)
    MergingSortedTransform 19 → 1
      MergeSortingTransform × 19
        LimitsCheckingTransform × 19
          PartialSortingTransform × 19
            (Union)
              (Expression)
              ExpressionTransform × 16
                (ReadFromMergeTree)
                MergeTreeThread × 16 0 → 1
              (ReadFromRemote)
```

TABLES SETTINGS:

table:
`ENGINE = Distributed(table_loc, sharding_key=C)`

local table_loc:
`ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY B SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192`

Comment: But to solve `WINDOW FUNCTION` `over (partition by C)` need to serialize all rows and it's done by a single thread at the server initiator inside Distributed table

Comment: I guess it can be calculated without `WINDOW FUNCTION` using many threads and at shards

Comment: @DennyCrane, i've added an answer based on your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WINDOW FUNCTION over (partition by C)` need to serialize all rows and it's done by a single thread at the server initiator inside `Distributed` table

One of the solutions would be to calculate without `WINDOW FUNCTION`, using many threads and at shards